# Databinding ApplicationSettings to Custom Components

Tags: c#, data-binding, custom-component

I have a custom component where I have implemented
`INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IBindableComponent`.

However, when I try to databind a property, the designer adds this
line:

```
this.component11.TestString =
global::WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.Setting;
```

instead of creating a binding as it does with a TextBox:

```
this.textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding(
   "Text",
   global::WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default,
   "Setting2",
   true,
   System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

I would have thought the designer would simply look to see if
`IBindableComponent` is implemented and if it is, generate the binding
coding instead of the assignment code.

Any ideas why this works with a textbox and not my custom component?

Here is my custom component:

```
public partial class Component1 : Component, INotifyPropertyChanged, IBindableComponent
    {
        public Component1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Component1(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string teststring;
        [Bindable(true)]
        public string TestString
        {
            get
            {
                return teststring;
            }
            set
            {
                if (teststring != value)
                {
                    teststring = value;
                    FirePropertyChanged("TestString");
                }
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IBindableComponent Members

        private BindingContext bindingContext = null;

        public BindingContext BindingContext
        {
            get
            {
                if (null == bindingContext)
                {
                    bindingContext = new BindingContext();
                }

                return bindingContext;
            }
            set { bindingContext = value; }
        }

        private ControlBindingsCollection databindings;

        public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings
        {
            get
            {
                if (null == databindings)
                {
                    databindings = new ControlBindingsCollection(this);
                }
                return databindings;
            }
            set { databindings = value; }
        }

        #endregion
    }

print("code sample");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
[ DesignerSerializationVisibility( DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden ),
  EditorBrowsable( EditorBrowsableState.Advanced ),
  Browsable( false ) ]
public BindingContext BindingContext {
    ...
}

[ ParenthesizePropertyName( true ),
  RefreshProperties( RefreshProperties.All ),
  DesignerSerializationVisibility( DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content ),
  Category( "Data" ) ]
public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work, the designer still generates the code:

this.component11.TestString = global::TestApplicationSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.TestSetting;

Instead of the correct binding code.  Any other ideas to look at?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Wait, that does work.  I just needed to recompile my component, delete and add it again after making your suggested changes.  Thanks very much!